# Why does `keyof any` have type of `string | number | symbol` in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The type `Record` in typescript is defined as:

```js
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
}
```

I don't understand why `keyof any` is used here.

After checking I found that the type of `keyof any` is `string | number | symbol`. Why is that?

Comment: Looks like a secret handshake indeed. I'd have used `PropertyKey` in place of `keyof any` to be more explicit. Although these include numbers, which can be set as keys but will be converted to strings, even for JS arrays.  So `string | symbol` is more accurate, if you want to read the results of something, including `Reflect.ownKeys` that, as of today, no longer include the `number` that can never happen.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`keyof any` represents the type of any value that can be used as an index to an object. Currently you can use `string` or `number` or `symbol` to index into an object.

```
let a: any;
a['a'] //ok
a[0] // ok
a[Symbol()] //ok
a[{}] // error
```

In the `Record` type, this `K extends keyof any` is used to constrain `K` to something that is a valid key for an object. So `K` could be `'prop'` or `'1'` or `string` but not `{a : string}`:

```
type t0 = Record<1, string> // { 1: string }
type t1 = Record<"prop", string> // { prop: string }
type t3 = Record<string, string> // { [name: string]: string }
type t4 = Record<number, string> // { [name: number]: string }
type t5 = Record<{a : string}, string> // error
```

The constraint is there, since whatever type is passed in `K` will become the keys of the resulting type, and thus `K` must be something that is a valid key for an object.

Comment: As far as I know `Record<number, string>` is not valid. You can use `const a: Record<string, string> = {}; a[1] = "hey"` and it is valid, but you cannot use number for the first type of `Record`, because as you said "`K` must be something that is a valid key for an object" - which is only a string or a symbol (numbers are coerced to strings).

Comment: @HelloWorld sure you can: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBMAsUF4oCUIGMD2AnAJgHgDsBXAWwCMIsAaKAZ2CwEsCBzAPgCgAbCYKADwBcMeEgDeUDlGlQAjMIBECjgF8OHfgG0ATAF1EUJRs0KAhgv1IFZBVAD0dylmxA TS supports number index signatures and it ensures only numbers are  used to index

Comment: My bad, realized I had `keyOfStringOnly=true`. As it was giving me: `TS2344: Type 'number' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'. error`

Comment: @HelloWorld that is an interesting observation.

Comment: if you know that the keys will be of a certain type, you can cast them with `yourVar as string`