# why do I have to add 'keyof' in front of 'any' type when use type mapping

Tags: typescript

I want to create new types, rather than transform a specific one, below is my code:

```
type CustomMapped<K extends any , T> = {                         //can't compile
    [P in K]: T
};
```

it doesn't compile, and the error is :

> Type K is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'

so I have to add `keyof` in front of any as:

```
type CustomMapped<K extends keyof any , T> = ...                 //can compile
```

I'm confused, if I rewrite the code as:

```
type CustomMapped<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = {    //also compile
    [P in K]: T
};
```

it compiles, so it means Type K **is** assignable to type `string | number | symbol`

so why the original error says Type K is **not** assignable to type `string | number | symbol`, and why I added `keyof` then it is OK?

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator works to create [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).

It expects a union of strings, number or symbols to effectively iterate through. As demonstrated in the documentation:

```js
type Keys = 'option1' | 'option2';
type Flags = { [K in Keys]: boolean };
```

`K` will become `option1` on the first "iteration" and `option2` on the second. However, if `Keys` were an object, this wouldn't work.

```js
type Keys = { option1: any; option2: any };
type Flags = { [K in Keys]: boolean }; 
//                   ^^^^
// Type 'Keys' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
```

Because `Keys` is not a `string`, `number` or `symbol` to iterate over, but an object. Since we want to iterate over the keys, this can be solved with the `keyof` operator to return `'option1' | 'option2'`.

With your example, you can update this with `[P in keyof K]` which will evalue to `[P in 'option1' | 'option2']` and work as expected:

```js
type CustomMapped<K extends any, T> = { [P in keyof K]: T };
```

Comment: I kind of get your idea, but what does `keyof any` mean? `any` is not an object, isn't it?

Comment: @secondimage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535598/why-does-keyof-any-have-type-of-string-number-symbol-in-typescript/55535722#55535722

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir   I think the root of my confusion is this question, cold you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110690/why-do-i-have-to-add-extends-keyof-in-front-of-type-when-use-type-mapping

Comment: @secondimage I think skovy does a good job of explaining it, This is just the way it is implemented the type after `in` provably must be a subtype of `keyof any` (that is `string | number | symbol`. Nothing else will do this is just a hard compiler requirement. If you would be mapping over `any` what should the compiler do, it would probably have to map over `string | number | symbol` so why not make sure the `any` didn't get in there my mistake.